# Polymer print part of a JSON object from String

Tags: javascript, json, date, polymer, dayofweek

I was wondering how to print a part of my JSON object in Polymer without it printing just the template code I wrote.

My JSON object looks like this:

```
weekDagenVertalingen:{
  type: Object,
  value:
  {
    'MONDAY':'Maandag',
    'TUESDAY':'Dinsdag',
    'WEDNESDAY':'Woensdag',
    'THURSDAY':'Donderdag',
    'FRIDAY':'Vrijdag',
    'SATURDAY':'Zaterdag',
    'SUNDAY':'Zondag'
  }
}
```

In javascript I'm able to do this:

```
var day = 'MONDAY';
console.log(weekDagenVertalingen[day]);
```

This Javascript code prints out:
`Maandag`

But for some reason when trying this:

```
{{weekDagenVertalingen[item.day]}}
```

It literally prints out this: {{weekDagenVertalingen[item.day]}} instead of the actual value of the JSON object.

I was thinking about getting the string this way:

```
{{weekDagenVertalingen.item.day}}
```

But I have no clue how to tell Polymer `item.day` is a value.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while since I've used Polymer, but I believe that you want a computed binding. Computed bindings only work one way (host to target).

```
...
<span>[[_getDay(item])]]</span>
...
<script>
  Polymer({
    ...
    _getDay: function(item) {
      return this.weekDagenVertalingen[item.day];
    }
  })
</script>
```

see: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding (scroll down until you see the computed bindings section)

Comment: Yes, essentially you can't have more than one variable as a binding _property_. Instead you'll need a binding _function_ (computed property).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks alot I just had no clue what to search for.